# loop.run_until_complete(g) got error of An asyncio.Future, a coroutine or an awaitable is required

Tags: python, python-asyncio

The following script

```
import asyncio

async def f(x):
    print(f'test {x}')
    raise Exception('error...')

g = lambda: f('x')
print(type(g))
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(g)  # error, change g to f also got the error
```

got the following error,

```
TypeError: An asyncio.Future, a coroutine or an awaitable is required
```

Tried call `loop.run_until_complete()` with both `g` and `f` and it got the same error?

Comment: You need to call your lambda to get a coroutine `loop.run_until_complete(g())`, at the moment you are just passing a function to `run_until_complete`

Comment: Yes, changed to `g()` works. However, I copied the script from a production code, which works. Very strange. BTW, why `loop.run_until_complete(f`)`  doesn't work? Isn't `f` already a coroutine?

Comment: Async functions are not coroutines until you call them, the same way that generator functions are not generators until you call them. They need to be initialised (called) before you can await them

Answer (score 2):

```py
>>> async def a():
...     pass
...

>>> a
<function a at 0x0000022F70FEA3B0>

>>> a()
<coroutine object a at 0x0000022F7100A2D0>
```

Just like generators as lain Shelvington said, coroutines are not coroutines until called.

But in case your company uses other concurrent libraries it may differ. What library your company uses?

```py
import trio
import anyio
import curio
import asyncio


async def f():
    print("run")

trio.run(f)
anyio.run(f)
curio.run(f)
asyncio.run(f)
```

```
run
run
run
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jupiterbjy\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharm2021.3\scratches\scratch.py", line 13, in <module>
    asyncio.run(f)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 37, in run
    raise ValueError("a coroutine was expected, got {!r}".format(main))
ValueError: a coroutine was expected, got <function f at 0x000001816CE9E200>
```

Comment: My company use asyncio and tornado. Maybe Tornado changed the behaver?

Comment: As far as I know it doesn't patch asyncio and change it's behavior, that mysterious company code sounds really interesting - too bad it's something can't be leaked out in public!